# Can't execute shell script from ssh command

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I have a script that will transfer a shell script from one server to another. The transferred script will change password for my user. I was able to transfer the script but it cannot execute it using ssh. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME=my_user
HOSTS="some.thing.host"
SCRIPT="/bin/sh /home/admin/my_user/tryscp.sh"
PASSWORDS=("init")
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
  /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p ${PASSWORDS[i]} scp /home/my_user/tryscp.sh my_user@some.thing.host:/home/admin/my_user
  /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p ${PASSWORDS[i]} ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
done
```

the scp part is working but the ssh with execution of the script on the remote server is not. I'm getting this error:

`"/bin/sh" isn't allowed to be executed.`

The content of the script that is being executed remotely via ssh is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -S echo -e "old_password\nnew_password\nnew_password" | passwd
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try with this `/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p ${PASSWORDS[i]} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"`

Comment: Hi Sir @cmak.fr, still getting the same error -- "/bin/sh" isn't allowed to be executed

Comment: Is `"/bin/sh" isn't allowed to be executed` the exact error - or did you translate it? Perhaps your user's login shell on the remote system is some kind of restricted execution shell such as [sudosh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sudosh)?

Comment: Yes it is the exact error that I get. The error was encountered when I'm trying to execute the change passwd script through ssh. But I can execute the passwd script on the remote server itself even if I'm not logged in as root.